# Ruby GUI Development on Mac/Linux and Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, macos, user-interface, cross-platform

I have following concern:

I should creat a application for a documentation tool (Tex/Word files to a final PDF). This tool requires a GUI and I would really love to write it in my fav programming lang **Ruby**.

*The main problem while asking my friend google was: every question was asked 3+ years ago and/or the libraries are outdated.*

So is there a nice way to get a **GUI with Ruby on Mac/Linux and Windows** (it would not bother me to create two different interfaces). Or are some better solutions out there (please no .java)

(Ruby on Rails could be a solution, but only browserbased ...)

Would be happy for your Ideas and Solutions :)

Best Regards
bMalum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I grepped #ruby channel logs and found that people often recommend [Shoes framework](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4) for Ruby GUI apps.

Since Shoes makes use of JRuby, it requires Java to run. It shouldn't be a problem if your software is intended for regular people, as Java is installed on most computers anyway.

- GitHub: https://github.com/shoes/shoes4
- Some tutorial: http://pragtob.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/shoes-4-a-progress-report/

Answer (score 3):

While there are some Ruby solutions for GUI, I would go for writing a Rails Web application and wrapping it with node-webkit instead. You will have a separate window for the application so it's kind of a native app, not a webapp. ;)

Please note you will need to bundle both node.js and Ruby binaries for the platforms you want to support. The most popular approach for node-webkit wrapped apps is AngularJS - then you don't have to bundle Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Gem LibUI for creating small GUI tools in Ruby. You can try it out if you like.

https://github.com/kojix2/libui

Comment: also https://github.com/AndyObtiva/glimmer-dsl-libui